# Compare two CGSize's to best persentage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, geometry, cgsize

Need your help, I have input CGSize (for example): **200x300**. And array with other `CGSize's = [20x20, 100x100, 150x150, 200x100, 200x250, 300x300...]`.
Please help me to find best item in array that have best compare percentage (for example its 200x250)...

I tried to use for enumerator, for example:

```
CGSize inputSize = CGSizeMake(200, 300);
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
    CGSize concurentSize = CGSizeZero;
    switch (i)
    {
     case 0:
     {
         concurentSize.width = 20;
         concurentSize.height = 20;
     }
     and so on...

    float differencePercentWidth = ( concurentSize.width / inputSize.width ) * 100.0;
    float differencePercentHeight = ( concurentSize.height / inputSize.height ) * 100.0;

    if (differencePercentWidth > 90 && differencePercentHeight > 90)
    {
        // FOUND best CGSize... stop
        break.
    }
}
```

But, its not working, it **differencePercentWidth/differencePercentHeight** can be > 100 =(

I need some of method or function that can compare 2 CGSize's in percent match... For example: size 200x300 is best matches with size 200x250... Something like:

```
float matchesInPerсent = CGSizeCompare(firstCGSize, secondCGSize);
//matchesInPerсent = 0.6; // in percents
```

Please help, sorry for my english, if you need more details, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Best compare percentage based on total pixels or per width and height?

Comment: The square root of the sum of the squared width and height differences might give you accurate results. You choose the size with the smallest value.

Comment: just to get it right to  200x300, a better fit would be 400x600 or 200x301 ?

Comment: @Jay yes, width and height in total, but smaller or equal to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Try the similar logic to calculate the maximum number in the array, but need to less then one finite value. In this cases calculate maximum percentage average of `size.width` and `size.height`, the maximum percentage which is closes to 1 is the winner. If you need the upper value of the 100% as well then you need to insert the logic to take that value below the 100% and run the same logic on those sizes as well.

Here is code which will give you closest percentage size from the array.

```
/*

sizes : array of the sizes represented in NSValue format 
size: The size for which you need closest value.

*/
- (CGSize)bestMatch:(NSArray *)sizes withSize:(CGSize)size {
        float bestMatch = 0.0;
        CGSize bestMatchSize = CGSizeZero;
        for (NSValue *value in sizes) {
            float percentage = (value.CGSizeValue.width/size.width + value.CGSizeValue.height/size.height)/2;

            //If you need greater then 100% and closes to the size
            if (percentage > 1.0) {
                percentage = -1*(percentage - 2);
            }

            if (bestMatch < percentage && percentage < 1) {
                bestMatch = percentage;
                bestMatchSize = value.CGSizeValue;
            }
        }
        //If you need best match you can return bestMatch which is closest in percentage

        return bestMatchSize;

 }
```